# Access client machines from public server in mutli tenant setup

Tags: java, linux, sockets, localtunnel

*In one line:* **How to connect multiple on-premise clients installations having private IP & behind a firewall to a public cloud hosted server and able to call HTTP endpoint & SSH in any of the on-premise clients setup from server.**

*Details:* We've multi-tenant application, in which we've one live public (or cluster of multiple) Tomcat server, which is deployed in public cloud (ex: AWS). We also have client Tomcat server which will be deployed in client place and obviously the on-premise hosted client will have private IP and will be firewalled (allowing communication on specific ports to our live server).

We've to support the on-premise client installations to support some functionalities of the app during client offline. But end user will be syncing from live server to client server periodically.

I need a efficient way to access private hosted client machine **(SSH & Tomcat)** from public server.

Setup:

- Language: **Java 8**
- App Server: **Tomcat 8**
- OS: **Ubuntu Linux 14.04 (both public cloud hosted & client servers)**

To my knowledge, below are the ways & their pros & cons to achieve this:

1. SSH reverse tunnel

   - Pros: No need for any additional programming
   - Cons: As the client count increases, those many ports need to be opened on the public server, which could raise many security issues.
2. Local tunnel services, like ngrock [or many other services](http://john-sheehan.com/blog/a-survey-of-the-localhost-proxying-landscape)

   - Pros: No need for hand coded program and probably they would have handled many edge cases like re-connection and keeping the connection alive even though it is idle for most of the time.
   - Cons: Most of them are commercial solutions and pricing model is per node. We'll be having at least 500-600 client installations.
3. Websockets - Server will send push and client will callbacks the server.

   - Pros: No need to open multiple ports on server
   - Cons: Only HTTP is possible, SSH is not possible
4. Hand coded socket programming where each client connects to separate port on server via SSH tunnel

   - Pros: We'll have full control
   - Cons: I m not sure how many edge cases we may have to handle, among which we might know many as of now.

Please suggest a better way to suit our requirement, keeping resource efficiency and security in mind.

Comment: The point here is that users want to access data inside the firewall from the public internet. If they really want this feature, they can pay the ngrok fee

Comment: People here are not from tech background. Beside, we are trying to push a new trend here - not something they are asking. You know its very difficult already :)

Comment: They don't need to understand tunneling, just that accessing their data from the Internet costs $10/month. If they are not willing to pay maybe you should not push this service. You can always develop your own solution or pay ngrok yourselves, depending on the development rate